# git how to confirm that l am behind the git repository

Tags: git

l can use `git status` to confirm what file l modified locally, but l don't know how to confirm that l am behind the git repository.

l always find out it when l push my code to git, or `git pull` before `git push` anytime. but l think it's not a smart way. l tried to google, but found nothing(maybe keywords' problem)

```
git add .
git commit -m "xxx"
git push
 ! [rejected]        master -> master (fetch first)
error: failed to push some refs to 
'git@code.xxx.com/xxxx'
hint: Updates were rejected because the remote contains work that you do
hint: not have locally. This is usually caused by another repository pushing
hint: to the same ref. You may want to first integrate the remote changes
hint: (e.g., 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.
```

Comment: When you `fetch` it checks the remote for new commits, but doesn't automatically `pull` them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The usual way to answer this question locally is to do a `git fetch`.  This will update the local tracking branch `origin/master`, which is what Git uses locally to figure out whether your local `master` branch is ahead or behind of the true remote `master` branch.  So all you need to do here is the following:

```
git fetch origin
git status
```

You might see output looking something like the following:

```
This branch is 2 commits ahead and 2 commits behind master
```

If this were your status, it would imply that you had made two commits since the point when you last synched.  And it would *also* mean that other people had laid down two commits to the remote `master` branch since the last sync.

Answer (score 0):

When someone else has pushed some new features or code you have to pull them first to get the new changes and merge them with your local state. If you have some conflicts you have to merge them and then you can push.

So i don't understand your problem that is the normal way.